# Why won't DrawToBitmap draw the contents of a different control?

Tags: c#, forms

This should be super straightforward and easy to do, but it's just not freaking working.  All I want to do is draw something to a `PictureBox` and then get a snapshot of the contents of the `PictureBox`.  Here's what I have:

```
Graphics g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawImage(_image, _imageRectangle);

using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, g))
{
    pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
    bmp.Save(_filePath);
}
```

The drawn image appears on the screen fine, but a blank `PictureBox` is drawn to `_filePath`.  What's going on?

Comment: if I was to guess, I would say the pictureBox1.ClientRectangle would be the problem. what if you were to replace it with new Rectangle(0,0,pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height)?

Comment: Don't use `CreateGraphics` - you need to handle the `Paint` event and draw your image on the picturebox there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
g.DrawLine(Pens.Yellow, 0,0, 600,600);

using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, g))
{
    pictureBox1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);
    bmp.Save(@"C:\test.jpg",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: ...wouldn't there be a yellow line throw the image?

Comment: Yes, I am drawing a yellow line through the image to show that it works.  I don't have your _image or your _imageRectangle so I substituted another Drawing function.